# identity.launchWebAuthFlow dont open popup in google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, identity

I want to use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow like this exemple :

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://auth.example.com/callback&scope=openid email",
        interactive: true
    }, function(redirectUri) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            // Error handling
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        } else {
            // Extract the code from the redirect URI
            var code = redirectUri.substring(redirectUri.indexOf("code=") + 5);
            // Use the code to obtain an access token
            // ...
        }
    });

});
```

But I have no popup that opens after my event click. And have any error in console or callback.

Any idea ?

Comment: Remove `interactive: false`.

Comment: yes it's a bad copy after a test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of chrome. Fixed after kill and restart chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, just change interactive from false to true, that will pop up the authentication flow, if you just need to get a new access token without the user having to re-enter the credentials, then you use interactive: false

Comment: yes it's a bad copy after a test